# dial tcp: lookup ip-x-x-xx.ec2.internal: no such host

Tags: go, tcp, apache-kafka, sarama

I am using github.com/Shopify/sarama package to interact with Kafka. In my current approach I could connect to the broker and get all topic names without a problem *(Consumer Code below)*.

However, when I try to delete some topic using the admin client *(Admin Code below)* I receive the "dial tcp: lookup ip-x-x-xx.ec2.internal: no such host" error.

I am out of ideas why I do receive this error. I would much appreciate any hints or possible solutions.

**Consumer**

```golang
    config := sarama.NewConfig()
    config.Consumer.Return.Errors = true

    //get broker
    cluster, err := sarama.NewConsumer("localhost:9092", config)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer func() {
        if err := cluster.Close(); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }()

    //get all topic from cluster
    topics, _ := cluster.Topics()
```

**Admin**

```golang
    config := sarama.NewConfig()
    config.Consumer.Return.Errors = true

    config.Version = sarama.V2_4_0_0

    //admin broker
    admin, err := sarama.NewClusterAdmin("localhost:9092", config)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }


    defer func() {
        if err := admin.Close(); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }()

    topic := []string{"test-topic"}
    output := admin.DeleteTopic(topic)

    if output == nil {
        fmt.Printf(" delete -  %s\n", topic[0])
    } else {
        fmt.Println(output)
    }
```

**Note** I am connecting over bastion instance into a remote by forwarding ssh ports.

---

## Update

after setting `sarama.Logger = log.New(os.Stdout, "[sarama] ", log.LstdFlags)` I get the following:

```
[sarama] 2020/03/25 02:08:03 Initializing new client
[sarama] 2020/03/25 02:08:03 client/metadata fetching metadata for all topics from broker localhost:9092
[sarama] 2020/03/25 02:08:04 Connected to broker at localhost:9092 (unregistered)
[sarama] 2020/03/25 02:08:04 client/brokers registered new broker #1001 at ip-x-x-x-1.ec2.internal:9092
[sarama] 2020/03/25 02:08:04 client/brokers registered new broker #1003 at ip-x-x-x-2.ec2.internal:9092
[sarama] 2020/03/25 02:08:04 client/brokers registered new broker #1002 at ip-x-x-x-3.ec2.internal:9092
[sarama] 2020/03/25 02:08:04 Successfully initialized new client
[sarama] 2020/03/25 02:08:04 Failed to connect to broker ip-x-x-x-3.ec2.internal:9092: dial tcp: lookup ip-x-x-x-3.ec2.internal: no such host`
```

---

## Update 2

my kafka server.properties:

```
advertised.listeners=INTERNAL://ip-x-x-x-1.ec2.internal:9091,EXTERNAL_INSECURE://ip-x-x-x-1.ec2.internal:9092
listeners=INTERNAL://:9091,EXTERNAL_INSECURE://:9092
listener.security.protocol.map=INTERNAL:SSL,EXTERNAL_INSECURE:PLAINTEXT
```

Comment: Seems like a network config issue, not golang. Try using netcat and telnet instead

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a client connects to the broker (in your case `localhost:9092`) the broker provides the client details of all the other brokers in the cluster. You can see this in your logs:

Initial connection

```
fetching metadata for all topics from broker localhost:9092
```

Details of brokers:

```
registered new broker #1001 at ip-x-x-x-1.ec2.internal:9092
registered new broker #1003 at ip-x-x-x-2.ec2.internal:9092
registered new broker #1002 at ip-x-x-x-3.ec2.internal:9092
```

The problem you have is that your client will subsequently use *these* broker details for further communication with the cluster. These addresses that the broker gives out are known as the *advertised listeners*. That is, the listeners that the broker "advertises".

**This means that your client must be able to *resolve and connect to the host & port* of the listener(s) that the broker returns at the initial connection**.

The reason hacking your `/etc/hosts` worked is that your local client can then resolve these addresses back to localhost and then the SSH forwarding works. But this is just a hack.

You should set your `advertised.listeners` in your *broker configuration* to addresses that a client can resolve (without needing any client-side `/etc/hosts` hacks).

To read more about this in detail see https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/

---

*Edit*: To be clear, you should set your `advertised.listeners` on each broker to the address that your *clients* can resolve - so if that's via 
 localhost SSH forwarding, set `advertised.listeners` to `localhost:9092`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I tried to follow up your blog but I couldn't make it work and I still get the same error.

in your **Option 2 - external address is NOT resolvable locally** example config you are using the following address:

`EXTERNAL://ec2-54-191-84-122.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:9092`

However, I don't have such addresses since the broker VMs are located in a private subnets.

I updated my question to include my currnet `server.properties` for one of the brokers.

Comment: Perfect, now it works. in addition, I had to do ssh tunnel and establish local listners for the rest of the brokers.

Answer (score 3):

so adding the brokers address to the known hosts `/etc/hosts` on my local machine where I execute the code did the trick.

**/etc/hosts:**

```
127.0.0.1 ip-x-x-x-1.ec2.internal
127.0.0.1 ip-x-x-x-2.ec2.internal
127.0.0.1 ip-x-x-x-3.ec2.internal
```

Though, I still don't understand why I didn't need to do this step when I was using `sarama.NewConsumer()`.